# Where is an SSD's cache location?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, cache

I often run heavy programs and it causes my SSD (Windows C:) to just lose a lot of space. I came up with an idea to symlink the cache location and a separate drive (that is always plugged in). The problem is that I cannot find the location of said cache. If you are wondering why I cannot just use inbuilt solutions to my problem, heres what happens:

[image: heres what happens]

I also cannot disable write caching as that means I wont be able to run heavy programs without trouble.

Comment: What are 'heavy programs'?

Comment: What is "the cache location?"  Browser cache?  Are you looking for where "big stuff" is stored that you can move safely?

Comment: SSD's don't have a "cache location" in the manner your describing.  You need to research your specific software and see if it has a setting for its cache. If it does not have a setting but you can find the folder location you can try relocating it with a link or junction.

Answer (score 0):

The system is most likely already doing what you want it to do. Writes to disk are cached in memory so that big blocks are written at a time since there is better performance on larger writes. For traditional rotating HDDs, the ordering of writes was extremely important for performance and so caching in memory allows data to be written in a more efficient order.

SSDs do not have the ordering problem but their data must be written in blocks and each block can be written to a limited number of times. For this reason, operating systems implement caching so that multiple logical writes to the same block are collated in a memory cache before sending them to the SSD. When a block was written to too many times, it fails and is removed from the list of good blocks which is why SSD space diminishes over time.

This is problematic for applications that make heavy use of file I/O. The only way around the issue is to use the SSD less. One way is to add RAM to your system so that more data can be cached  before it must be written. This works best for certain pattern of disk usage. Another option if you have a small working set that is written frequently is to install a RAMDisk which simulates a drive in memory. This has a huge impact on performance and this is what I recommend TMP/TEMP folders. It has disadvantages such as running out of space for some applications which make huge temporary files (Think gigapixel panorama assembly, Blu-Ray writing, etc).

Finally, on most desktops you can simply add a standard HDD and use it for some applications. A lot of software can be installed on a custom path but, most importantly, the disk they work with can often be specified separately. For example Photoshop allows users to specify scratch disks and Autopano Giga has a dedicated setting select where to store intermediate files which can get huge.
Those are quite a bit slower than SSDs but have excellent longevity.

Comment: This is correct, but the OP says the cache "uses a lot of space" because of "heavy programs," which does not sound like write caching. It is not entirely clear if the OP is actually asking about the of HDD/SSD cache or rather some space for temporary files that is not being cleared.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused slightly about the wording. I understood it as 'loses a lot of space' in the sense that the drive is reporting a lower size over time. I'll clarify the last point as it could be used for large data sets.

Comment: na i set my TMP/TEMP to R:/Cache2/ which is not on the SSD